# Getting jackson serialization issue for inputstream object

Tags: java, excel, apache, serialization, jackson

I am getting the following exception when trying to serialize using jackson

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer
>   found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain:
>   com.olacabs.deviceplatform.common.entities.WrappedInputStream["wb"]->org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook["packagePart"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["zipArchive"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.FakeZipEntry["inputStream"])

I tried the solution as explained in http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonmappingexception where we use the following piece of code to make visibility as All  `mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);`

After that it resulting in stackoverflow error.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite
>   recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartCollection["/_rels/.rels"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart["_container"]->org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage["partList"].... clipped

Code
Custom WrappedInputStreamclass

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WrappedInputStream implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12358903454875L;

    private String transactionKey;
    private Workbook wb;
}
```

Workbook has inputStream in it at some level.. even if i include inputStream directly from multipartFile object, it results in the same issue.

Code where error occurs()

```
public boolean uploadData(MultipartFile inventoryData) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inventoryData.getInputStream());
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WrappedInputStream wrappedInputStream = new WrappedInputStream(key, wb);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        String wrappedInputStreamString = mapper.writeValueAsString(wrappedInputStream); //exception occurs at this place

//process the string further
}
```

Anyone knows the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your DTO's and add the annotation @JsonIgnore on the child class where you mention the reference to the parent class.

```
@JsonIgnore
private Member member;
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: That class is third party, in this case its inputStream.. cannot make any changes to it.

Comment: Can you please share your code with me so that i can further inspect and help on this ?.Thanks.